# Azure DB for PostgreSQL - changes to log_line_prefix parameter not implemented

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-database-postgresql

I have a General Purpose Single Server instance of Azure DB for PostgreSQL where I have installed the pgAudit plugin.
I am trying to add more data to the pgAudit session auditing entries by following the instructions on [Microsoft's page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-audit#pgaudit-settings) and [PostgreSQL's page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-LINE-PREFIX) and I tried to set up log_line_prefix in the following configurations:

- t=%t c=%c a=%a u=%u d=%d r=%r% h=h% e=e c=%c
- %t,%c,%a,%u,%d,%r,%h,%e,%c
- %t%c%a%u%d%r%h%e%c

None of these have any effect on events collected. Here's the most of what an INSERT looks like:

```
{
  "LogicalServerName": "postgresql4moi",
  "SubscriptionId": "****",
  "ResourceGroup": "OLC_Research",
  "time": "2020-05-05T12:10:59Z",
  "resourceId": "***",
  "category": "PostgreSQLLogs",
  "operationName": "LogEvent",
  "properties": {
    "prefix": "t=2020-05-05 12:10:59 UTC c=5eb157c4.5c a=DBeaver 7.0.1 - SQLEditor <testingScript.sql> u=system d=postgres r=****.234(4344)h=he=e c=5eb157c4.5c",
    "message": "AUDIT: SESSION,6,1,WRITE,INSERT,,,\"INSERT INTO public.koko_table VALUES ('kokoMoko','kokoMoko')\",<none>",
    "detail": "",
    "errorLevel": "LOG",
    "domain": "postgres-11",
    "schemaName": "",
    "tableName": "",
    "columnName": "",
    "datatypeName": ""
  }
}
```

Is there something else I forgot to configure?
I event restarted the database after each attempt to set the parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first log_line_prefix in your question seems to be under the prefix key in the properties field. Is that not what you're expecting?

Comment: @AdamKG no, it was not. There are other small bugs I found with this log. I opened a support ticket with Microsoft, they're very responsive.